# Feeling for rejection followed by acceptance?

Tags: phrases, idioms

Is there any good word/phrase/idiom for that feeling of scorn when you're accepted by someone/something after getting rejected the first time?

I remember a phrase being quoted by Nathan Fillion in *Castle* when Richard Castle's daughter is rejected to Stanford and later gets in. Still can't remember the lines, just the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's [***spite***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spite) you're after:

From The Free Dictionary:

> n. Malicious ill will prompting an urge to hurt or humiliate another person.
>   v. to annoy in order to vent spite

You could say,

> "Oh, *now*, they finally accept me after rejecting me a few months ago.  Well, I'm gonna turn 'em down just to **spite** them."

Comment: Yup. That's exactly what I was looking for-harboring resent over rejection.

Answer (score 2):

*[Indignant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/indignant)* might be a synonym for the feeling of scorn (which is a great word on its own merit):

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Feeling or showing anger or annoyance at what is perceived as unfair
>   treatment:
>
> Origin
>
> late 16th century: from Latin indignant- 'regarding as unworthy', from
>   the verb indignari, from in- 'not' + dignus 'worthy'.

When they rejected you, they despised your dignity, and now their dignity is diminished in your mind, because they rushed to a faulty judgement against you.

Answer (score 1):

[Leave a bad taste in  the mouth](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/leave+a+bad+taste+in+mouth) , may suggest such a feeling:

> - if an experience leaves a bad taste in your mouth, you have an unpleasant memory of it
>
>   - The whole business about the missing money left a bad taste in his mouth. It was a very nice hotel, but something about it left a bad taste in my mouth. (TFD)

- The experience of being finally accepted after having been rejected, may reasonably leave a bad taste in the mouth!!

Comment: Interesting. I was thinking more in terms of scorned lover, maybe?

Comment: I was thinking about *sour grapes* that works with this: It appears the grapes were indeed sour.

Answer (score 1):

*[Forlorn](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/forlorn)* would imply a sadness at the rejection:

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1. Pitifully sad and abandoned or lonely:

It could also imply the apprehension of your future in that relationship:

> 2. (Of an aim or endeavour) unlikely to succeed or be fulfilled:

The etymology suggests a ***lostness***:

> Origin
>
> Old English forloren 'depraved, morally abandoned', past participle of
>   forlēosan 'lose',
>
> of Germanic origin; related to Dutch verliezen and German verlieren,
>   and ultimately to for- and lose.
>
> sense 1 dates from the 16th century.

OED

Answer (score 0):

Consider the term *[vindicate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vindicate)*

> to show that (someone or something that has been criticized or doubted) is correct, true, or reasonable

*Merriam-Webster*

The term is also used to describe proving innocence.

A person who was rejected and then accepted might say *I feel vindicated!*

The noun form is *vindication*

**Supplement**

If you are looking for a phrase to express rejection by the formerly rejected, you could say

- [that ship has sailed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/that-or-the-ship-has-sailed) *Oxford Dictionary Online*
- [too little, too late](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/too+little,+too+late) *thefreedictionary.com*

Comment: uhh..not quite, I think. The feeling I'm referring to has more of a negative connotation to it.

Comment: I like the "too little, too late" that you added on to this.

Answer (score 0):

*[Antipathy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/antipathy)* comes to mind:

> NOUN
>
> [MASS NOUN]
>
> A deep-seated feeling of aversion:

This is a general bad feeling in its [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=antipathy&allowed_in_frame=0):

> c.1600,
>
> from Latin antipathia,
>
> from Greek antipatheia, noun of state
>
> from antipathes "opposed in feeling, having opposite feeling; in
>   return for suffering; felt mutually,"
>
> from anti- "**against**" (see anti-) + root of pathos "**feeling**" (see
>   pathos).
>
> **Emphasis** mine